# How to test Intl with jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I need to test a code with Intl, and we use jasmine for that.

When I test this line of code

```
new Intl.NumberFormat("fr-FR").format(3500)
```

I wish this result: **"3 500"**, in broswer it's good I have this string. but in jasmine this code return **"3,500"** and it's not good for me.

all my code:

```
describe("test Intl", function() {
   it("fr-FR", function() {
    expect(new Intl.NumberFormat("fr-FR").format(3500)).toBe("3 500");
   });
});
```

I don't understand why jasmine Intl return "3,500" and not "3 500"

Comment: Are you running the Jasmine Tests in the browser? or using commandline?

Comment: I run the Jasmine Test with gulp and nodejs, so I use a commandline